# Bluemix SDK vs. MobileFirst SDK

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mobile-services

I am pretty sure this question might seem silly but will throw it anyway.

I have started playing around with Bluemix and its fabulous Push, Data, Analiytics and more services. The main point is to develope an Android application leveraging these services. The problem is that I haven't found consistency in the official documentation.

For instance,

- [Here](http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/android#set-up-android) you'll see that it makes use of some "local" (the download link can be found on the top of that page so that you can copy them into you `lib` folder) libraries. The push `IntentService` is `com.ibm.mobile.services.push.IBMPushIntentService`.
- On the other side, in [this official sample code](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-android-hellopush/blob/master/helloPush/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) you will notice that the `IntentService` is `com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushIntentService`.

I hope I have explained my point on this issue.

Both pages seem to be up-to-date so, my dumb question is, **what is the difference?** and **which SDK should I use?**

Comment: I think this may help: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/12/15/important-mobile-services-announcement/.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier thanks for the clarification. I appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first link you referenced is for the sun-setting, deprecated 1st generation of Moblie Cloud services on Bluemix, AKA MBaaS. The getting started documentation for MBaaS will be removed shortly. You can see the recent deprecation announcement [here](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/12/15/important-mobile-services-announcement/).

The sample you link is the correct sample for the 2nd generation, and most recent, versions of IBM MobileFirst Services (IMF). You can find the appropriate documentation for Push Notifications [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/index.html). You'll notice, all the docs are now hosted on the Bluemix docs page, instead of mbaas-gettingstarted...

Apologies for any confusion this has caused.